# JPA Criteria multiselect with fetch - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have following model and struggling with it to retrieve results from my query:

```
@Entity
public class MyData {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "security_id")
    private Long securityId;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private MyDataDetails myDataDetails;

    MyData() {
    }

//other fields here
//omitted getters/setters
}

@Entity
public class MyDataDetails {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    @Column(name = "owner")
    private String owner;

    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private LocalDateTime createdOn;

    MyDataDetails() {
    }
//other fields here
//omitted getters/setters
}
```

Now I would like to query only columns: id, securityId, and myDataDetails which referes to MyDataDetails entity (not complete entity, because it has many other properties and I would like to have best performance).

When I write query:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query = builder.createTupleQuery();
    Root<MyData> root = query.from(MyData.class);
    ///query.select(root).distinct(true);
    root.fetch(MyDataDetail_.myDataDetails, JoinType.LEFT);
     query.distinct(true).multiselect(
                root.get(MyDataDetail_.id),
                root.get(MyDataDetail_.securityId), root.get(MyDataDetail_.myDataDetails));
  entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList().stream()
                .map(tuple -> new MyDto(tuple.get(0, String.class), null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
                        null, null, null, 0, tuple.get(13, MyDataDetails.class)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the
>   owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list
>   [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy
>   properties,classAlias=generatedAlias1,role=MyData.myDataDetails,tableName=***,tableAlias=***da1_,origin=****
>   ****,columns={***0*.id ,className=MyDataDetails}}] [select distinct  generatedAlias0.id,
>   generatedAlias0.securityId, generatedAlias0.myDataDetails from MyData
>   as generatedAlias0 left join fetch generatedAlias0.myDataDetails as
>   generatedAlias1 where ( ( 1=1 ) and (
>   generatedAlias0.owningAuthority=:param0 ) ) and ( 1=1 )]

Comment: Instead of selecting root.get(MyDataDetail_.myDataDetails) I selected each field of myDataDetails separately root.get(MyDataDetail_.myDataDetails).get("someField"), fetching in a LEFT join manner I didn't see innej join in sql query and see results without myDataDetails as well as with them so I don't loose any results.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make `fetch` work, you have to return the full owner entity.
E.g. like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery< MyData > query = builder.createQuery(MyData.class);
Root<MyData> root = query.from(MyData.class);

root.fetch(MyDataDetail_.myDataDetails, JoinType.LEFT);
query.distinct(true).select(root);
  entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList().stream()
                .map(e -> new MyDto(e.getId(), null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
                        null, null, null, 0, e.getMyDataDetails()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```